# Automatic click a button when the page loads with GreaseMonkey

Tags: jquery, greasemonkey

I am new to Grease Monkey and I need to click this Delete button

```
<TD nowrap width="20" height="18" valign="middle" align="center"><A href="JavaScript:SetCmd(document.msgViewer.CmdDelete.value);" title="Delete"><IMG border="0" src="https://webmail.myweb.com.au/exchweb/img/delete.gif" alt="Delete"></A></TD>
```

after the page is loaded using Grease Monkey

Full page here:

http://pastebin.com/DUytjGAh

Is this possible and how should I go about it?

This is so that I can delete my more than 10K spam email automatically. I already selected all the email items using Grease Monkey so now I need to press the Delete button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one case where it's perfectly fine to use [unsafeWindow](http://wiki.greasespot.net/UnsafeWindow).

So assuming that the emails are properly selected (which may be more than just checking a checkbox) and any AJAX delays/reloading are accounted for, then this code should do the trick:

```
unsafeWindow.SetCmd (unsafeWindow.document.msgViewer.CmdDelete.value);
```

Alternatively, you may find it easier to [generate a click event](http://wiki.greasespot.net/Generate_Click_Events#Generating_a_Click_Event).

Comment: This is my code: http://pastebin.com/5kVuxHHT The checking of the checkboxes works but not unsafeWindow.SetCmd (unsafeWindow.msgViewer.CmdDelete.value); Is there something I did wrongly?

Comment: Updated the answer.  Looks like it should be: `unsafeWindow.SetCmd (unsafeWindow.document.msgViewer.CmdDelete.value);`.

Answer (score 1):

Just run the JavaScript as defined in the href parameter of the anchor tag.

Comment: How do I do that walkietokyo in this case?

Answer (score 0):

after checking the desired emails to delete,
`SetCmd(document.msgViewer.CmdDelete.value);`